# How can I search text using regex when it contains \r\n

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2's regex search and replace tool and would like to search text that includes the `\r and \n` special characters but cannot see how just at the moment.

For example, I have the text:

```
<div class="head">\r\n    


\r\n    Keep this text\r\n</div>
```

Which I would like to transform into:

```
<h1>Keep this text</h1>
```

I would also like to factor in the eventuality that these `\r\n` characters may not be present.

How might I search accounting for `\r\n` being present and absent, and then remove them as per above? If two regex are required that's fine too.

So far I have `<div class="head">(\w)+</div>`, however this is stalled by the aforementioned `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `\s`, which matches white space.

So your regex should be something like the following:
`<div class="head">\s*(.+?)\s*</div>`

Comment: Thanks this works. Does look a few divs ahead however. By this I mean it chooses to close it's match not on the closing div of div class head but the next along. I'll keep tinkering with it though, cheers.

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime Try with `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`. It will match the *first* encountered `</div>`

Comment: Ahh... wasn't considering full HTML, just the sample like the OP showed. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do this in ST2, then I think it would fit your need:

Find:

```
<div class="head">[\s\r\n]*([\w ]+)[\s\r\n]*<\/div>
```

Replace by:

```
<h1>$1</h1>
```

[Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/qD5tQ8)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it works well in your demo however no in sublime unfortunately. I've adapted the first answer below using your example so cheers.

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime Cheers! Yea, it's a bit of a problem when different apps treat regex differently ^^ Glad to have helped a bit though!